# RxSwift: Convert Observable to a Variable

Tags: rx-swift

How do I convert an Observable of type Int to a Variable of type Int?

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
let obs: Observable<Int> = Observable.of(4)

let variable: Variable<Int> = obs
    .flatMap { num in
        return Variable<Int>(num)
    }
```

Using flatMap feels like the most logical way of doing the conversion, however, I get a compiler error which essentially says that it does not like the flatMap returning anything that is not an observable. Any ideas?

EDIT:

Just to give some context as to why I need to convert the Observable into a Variable:

I need my viewModel to drive a UIPickerView inside a ViewController. Currently, I have two exposed properties in my ViewModel, items: Observable<[String]> (which is the datasource for the UIPickerView) and selectedIndex: Variable. The selectedIndex will drive the initial value of the UIPickerView but also keep track of any changes the user makes.

The reason I needed to convert from the Observable to Variable was that I needed to figure out which index of the UIPickerView should be selected initially:

```
items.map { days -> Int in
    if let index = days.index(where: { str in
        return str == selectedDay
    }) {
        return index
    }
    return 0
}
.flatMap { num in
    return Variable<Int>(num)
}
```

I'm now wondering if I'm over complicating things, and if instead of the Variable in I should just have an Observable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A few points here:

First, You should *not* use `Variable` as it's deprecated (gonna be entirely deprecated in Swift 5 probably). Look at `BehaviorSubject` and `BehaviorRelay` instead.

About your question, I'm not sure what is the use case for having a `Variable` equal to an Observable, so there are two different thoughts I have:

1. You can bind an Observable to a Variable/Subject/Relay (e.g. `observable.bind(to: variable)`)
2. You can actually go the other way around an get an Observable *from* the Variable, which might make more sense. e.g. `variable.asObservable()`

Comment: Thanks, I did not know that the Variable will become deprecated soon so that’s a great tip. My use case for using a Variable<Int> is I wanted to track the selected row of UIPickerView in my ViewModel. The conversion from observable would help me figure out what is the initially selected index (i.e. I would look up the Observable<[String]> and return a Variable<Int> for the index that was selected).

Comment: UIPickerView already has a Reactive Extension for that (picker.rx.itemSelected). You might want to check that out.